# Getting CMake on Windows to find the vc120 Boost libraries

Tags: boost, cmake, visual-studio-2015

CMake is looking for a different boost files than I have installed, and I don't know how to fix it.  I'm on 64-bit Windows 7, VisualStudio Community 2015, and using the latest 64-bit build of Boost [boost_1_58_0-msvc-12.0-64.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.58.0/).

The relevant part of my CMake file is this:

```
SET          ( Boost_DEBUG                ON  )
SET          ( Boost_DETAILED_FAILURE_MSG ON  )
SET          ( Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS      ON  )
SET          ( Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED    ON  )
SET          ( Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME   OFF )
FIND_PACKAGE ( Boost COMPONENTS regex date_time REQUIRED )
```

With debug and detailed messages enabled, I can see CMake is looking in the right place, but is looking for "vc140" instead of "vc120":

```
location of version.hpp: C:/boost_1_58_0/boost/version.hpp
version.hpp reveals boost 1.58.0
guessed _boost_COMPILER = -vc140
_boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
_boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
_boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -gd
_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = C:\boost_1_58_0\lib64-msvc-12.0;C:\boost_1_58_0/lib;C:\boost_1_58_0/stage/lib;C:/boost_1_58_0/lib;C:/boost_1_58_0/../lib;C:/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
Searching for REGEX_LIBRARY_RELEASE:
libboost_regex-vc140-mt-1_58;
libboost_regex-vc140-mt;
libboost_regex-mt-1_58;
libboost_regex-mt;
libboost_regex
```

The files I have are named with "120":

```
>dir /b c:\boost_1_58_0\lib64-msvc-12.0\libboost_regex-*
libboost_regex-vc120-mt-1_58.lib
libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib
libboost_regex-vc120-mt-s-1_58.lib
libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_58.lib
libboost_regex-vc120-s-1_58.lib
libboost_regex-vc120-sgd-1_58.lib
```

I'm assuming "120" refers to the version of VisualStudio?  How do I get CMake to find the vc120 files?

Answer (score 3):

Little known variable called `Boost_COMPILER` is the solution.  So in my case, to force CMake to look for vc120 instead of the default vc140, I have to run cmake like this:

```
>cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBoost_COMPILER=-vc120 -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\boost_1_58_0 -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\boost_1_58_0\lib64-msvc-12.0 -G "Visual Studio 14" ..
```

Comment: I'm not sure how well this work - you're going to be building your own code using VC14, but linking with Boost libs which were built with VC12.  It might be safer to just download the Boost sources and build the required libs with VC14?

Comment: In the end, I gave up and went back to an earlier version of Visual Studio. Was having problems compiling some template code in the pre-release VS 2015.  So I don't know if @Fraser was right and this would eventually have caused problems.